# Multi-column input to ML.PREDICT for a TensorFlow model in BigQuery ML

Tags: tensorflow, google-bigquery

I trained a TensorFlow classifier and created it as a model in BigQuery ML using `CREATE MODEL`. Now I would like to use `ML.PREDICT` to batch predict using this model. I get the error **"Invalid table-valued function ml.predict Column inputs is not found in the input data to the PREDICT function."**

Here's my query:

```
select * from ml.predict (
  model test.digital_native_classifier_kf, 
  (select * from dataset_id.features_table_id)
)
```

In the BigQuery documentation, they give an example for a TensorFlow model with a single column aliased as `input` so the TensorFlow `input_fn` can accept it. However, this classifier accepts hundreds of features. How do I specify the query passed to `ML.PREDICT` so it uses *all* the columns in my features table?

Comment: From the examples here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-predict what you are doing is correct. Are you sure your features table contains all the required columns? Compare the model and table schemas

Comment: Yes, it's the exact same table I used to train the model locally with TensorFlow.

Comment: I would test with few features first and list the column names explicitly rahter than using * first as a sanity check

Answer (score 1):

After you load the model into BigQuery ML, click on the model in the BigQuery UI and switch over to the "Schema" tab. This should tell you what features (column names) the model wants.

It is possible that when you created the TensorFlow/Keras model you did not assign names to the input nodes. Then, the feature names might have been auto-assigned to something like int1 and float2.

Alternately, run the program saved_model_cli on the model (it's a python program that comes with tensorflow) to see what the supported signature is

```
saved_model_cli show --dir $export_path --all
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research, Auto ML encodes the input Tensors as Prensors which is a serialized string format shoved into a Tensor.

This means that you can't import the AutoML model from GCS directly into BQML the way you would import a TensorFlow model that explicitly encoded the different inputs as a json struct.

So, in order to import an AutoML model into BigQuery ML, the BigQuery engineering team would need to add support for something like `model_type='automl'` in addition to `model_type='tensorflow'`.

Answer (score -1):

At the moment multi-column is not possible, from the [AutoML Beginners guide](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/beginners-guide#how_does_work):

> One column from your dataset, called the target, is what your model will learn to predict. Some number of the other data columns are inputs (called features) that the model will learn patterns from. You can use the same input features to build multiple kinds of models just by changing the target.

Also found this feature request to [Multi-target AutoML Tables Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/134941089)

Comment: My question is about BigQuery ML, not AutoML. Do they use the same backend?

Comment: sorry not the same, maybe is a [syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-predict#mlpredict_syntax) 
issue? try with `[PROJECT_ID].[DATASET].[MODEL]` (including the backticks)

Comment: that statement is about multiple outputs, not multiple inputs.