# Multi-column input to ML.PREDICT for a TensorFlow model in BigQueryML

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-automl

We have trained a model in Google Cloud AutoML (a tool that we like a lot) and successfully exported it to GCS, and then created the model in BigQuery using the below command:

```
create or replace model my_dataset.my_bq_ml_model
options(model_type='tensorflow',
 model_path='my gcs path to exported tensorflow model'))
```

However, when we use BigQueryML to try and run some predictions using the model we are unsure of the how to format the multiple features that our model uses into the single "inputs" string the exported Tensorflow model accepts in BigQuery.

```
select  *
from    ml.predict(model my_project.my_dataset.my_bq_ml_model,
(
 select 'How do we format this?'  as inputs
 from my_rows_to_predict
))
```

Has anyone done this yet?

This is similar to this question, which remains open:
[Multi-column input to ML.PREDICT for a TensorFlow model in BigQuery ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570155/multi-column-input-to-ml-predict-for-a-tensorflow-model-in-bigquery-ml)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

After you load the model into BigQuery ML, click on the model in the BigQuery UI and switch over to the "Schema" tab. This should tell you what columns the model wants.

Alternately, run the program saved_model_cli on the model (it's a python program that comes with tensorflow) to see what the supported signature is

```
saved_model_cli show --dir $export_path --all
```

Comment: Hi Lak thank you for the above.  We followed the steps above and her is the output. 

https://pastebin.com/HCbpZT20

However, we are not sure how we translate this into the signature for the inputs string to the model in BigQueryML.

Are you able to advise please?

Comment: Unfortunately, the saved_model_cli wasn't very helpful -- it doesn't tell you the schema of the inputs, only that it is a string ... inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1). and that isn't any help. Maybe try putting the data in JSON format?